# How to convert a Spark Dataframe column from vector to a set?

Tags: python, set, pyspark, data-conversion, apache-spark-sql

I need to process a dataset to identify frequent itemsets. So the input column must be a vector. The original column is a string with the items separated by comma, so i did the following:

```
functions.split(out_1['skills'], ',')
```

The problem is the, for some rows, I have duplicated values in the `skills` and this is causing an error when trying to identify the frequent itemsets.

I wanted to convert the vector to a set to remove the duplicated elements. Something like this:

```
functions.to_set(functions.split(out_1['skills'], ','))
```

But I could not find a function to convert a column from vector to set, i.e., there is no `to_set` function.

How can I accomplish what I want, i.e., remove the duplicated elements from the vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the `set` function in python to a udf using `functions.udf(set)` and then apply it to the array column:

```
df.show()
+-------+
| skills|
+-------+
|a,a,b,c|
|  a,b,c|
|c,d,e,e|
+-------+

import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.withColumn("unique_skills", F.udf(set)(F.split(df.skills, ","))).show()
+-------+-------------+
| skills|unique_skills|
+-------+-------------+
|a,a,b,c|    [a, b, c]|
|  a,b,c|    [a, b, c]|
|c,d,e,e|    [c, d, e]|
+-------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 4):

It is recommended, when possible, to use native spark functions instead of UDFs for efficiency reasons. There is a dedicated function to leave only unique items in an array column: `array_distinct()` introduced in **spark 2.4.0**

```
from pyspark import Row
from pyspark.shell import spark
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    Row(skills='a,a,b,c'),
    Row(skills='a,b,c'),
    Row(skills='c,d,e,e'),
])

df = df.withColumn('skills_arr', F.array_distinct(F.split(df.skills, ",")))
```

result:

```
+-------+----------+
|skills |skills_arr|
+-------+----------+
|a,a,b,c|[a, b, c] |
|a,b,c  |[a, b, c] |
|c,d,e,e|[c, d, e] |
+-------+----------+
```